# While loop construct in combination with getline function that continues until EOF

Tags: c++

I am in a bind right now and the most frustrating thing about this is that I know what the problem is but, I cannot fix it :(...

My goal is to ultimately use getline to read lines of strings from redirected input (from a text file) and keep going until EOF is reached.

**Example text file (contents):**

Hello World!

Good Bye.

**My source code(only includes the section where it will not work):**

```
while (!(getline(std::cin, s_array)).eof()){ // it won't read second line
//do some awesome stuff to the first line read!
}
```

As far as I know, getline reads everything upto the newline and stops so how do we get it to keep reading because it always stops at Hello World!.

Comment: Your brackets are not even balanced...

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad X.X, rest assured that they are indeed right in the code, I must have typed it wrong in post.

Comment: You can still edit your post. However, consider deleting it altogether and then carefully reading the posting guidelines, especially those concerning help with code snippets that don't work as intended.

Comment: Alright thanks for tip :D!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `while (getline(std::cin, s_array)) { }` instead.

`std::getline()` returns `istream&`, and `istream::operator void*()` makes it evaluated as `false` whenever any error flag is set.

Comment: How come we don't include EOF anywhere, does the getline fucntion implicitly stop at EOF?

Comment: @user152573 read the documentation for functions that you are calling. If `getline` fails to read a line then the stream goes into an error state. You do not need to ever check `eof`, you only need to know whether you succeeded or failed to read a line.

Comment: You do need `eof()` to distinguish a failure due to EOF from a parsing failure, though that's not the case when only reading strings without any parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely read Joseph Mansfield's blog post titled ["Don't condition input on eof()"](http://josephmansfield.uk/articles/dont-condition-input-on-eof.html) which describes this pitfall in details and provides a well justified guideline.